# Functional analysis problem.

Tags: functions, contest-math, quadratics

Find the smallest value of $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x-9}$ on the interval $(9, +\infty)$.

We should basically find the biggest $a$ such that $\frac{x^2}{x-9} \geq a$. We can multiply both sides by $x-9$ since it's positive and than we get $x^2-ax+9a \geq 0.$ I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What did you try? Write down your own work in the body of your question, lest it'll be downvoted and even closed.

Comment: @DonAntonio will do soon

Comment: You tagged your question "analysis, functional analysis" and etc. Do you know about derivatives, what their sign tells you about the function, extreme points and etc.? BTW' your way is good, too: when is an upwards parabola "hoovering" over the x-axis all the time? Find out this and you'll get your minimal value...!

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm familiar with them(though not well), however I'd prefer a solution without them. Still, wouldn't reject a derivative solution.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there: $\;x^2-ax+9a\ge0\iff \Delta\le0\;$ ,where $\;\Delta:=\,$ the discriminant of the given quadratic. Can you continue from here? Without derivatives and stuff: just basic algebra and basic geometry.

Comment: thanks, that leads to the solution directly!

Comment: Indeed it does, when we identify the minimal value of that function with the $\;y\,-$ value of the vertex of the parabola $\;x^2-ax+9a\;$ ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a purely algebraic way using the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean (AM-GM):

For $x>9$ we have

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{x^2}{x-9}
& = & \frac{x^2-81+81}{x-9} \\
& = & x+9 + \frac{81}{x-9} \\
& = & x-9 + \frac{81}{x-9} + 18 \\
& \stackrel{AM-GM}{\geq} & 2\sqrt{81} + 18\\
& = & 36
\end{eqnarray*}

Equality holds if and only if

$$x-9 = \frac{81}{x-9} \stackrel{x>9}{\Leftrightarrow} x=18$$

Comment: thanks, this method is very nice too!

Answer (score 2):

Rephrased:

$y:=x-9,$ $y\in (0,\infty)$;

$f(y)=\dfrac{(y+9)^2}{y} =$

$y+18+\dfrac{81}{y}=$

$(y^{1/2}-\dfrac{9}{y^{1/2}})^2+18+18 \ge 36;$

Equality for

$y^{1/2}=\dfrac{9}{y^{1/2}}$,

$y=9.$